# Is it possible to change a line from a ggplot/geom_line plot depending on what month the datapoint corresponds to?

Tags: r

Would like to know if it is possible to make a geom_line be red when it's between sept-feb and blue for the rest of the months?[image: the graph i would like to change line colour]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498588/ggplot-line-plot-different-colors-for-sections/47498831

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756336/change-color-for-just-part-of-a-line

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. The easiest way to do it by creating a vector of your colors, the same length as the rows in your dataframe, and passing it to the `col` argument in `geom_line()`.

Here is an example:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# create some dates and values
df <- tibble(
  date = today() + seq(from = -365, to = 0, by = 30),
  value = runif(length(date), min = 300, max = 800)
) 

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_line(
    col = ifelse(month(df$date) %>% between(3, 8), "blue", "red")
  ) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: seem to get an error message when I try to reproduce it with my df `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (81): colour`

Comment: You need to make sure the vector is the same length as your data - as stated in the answer. Edit this part of the code to make a vector of `red` and `blue`s the same length as your df: `ifelse(month(df$date) %>% between(3, 8), "blue", "red")`

Comment: If you update your question with some data, we might be able to help you better @P_S_13.